# Timed locks in GCD?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch

**Use case**:

1. There is a lot of requests that should be processed.
2. The time taken to process each request varies.
3. Request are meant to be processed concurrently (now they are pushed into the global queue got by `dispatch_get_global_queue`).
4. Requests coming from the same client **preferably** should be processed synchronously, e.g., processing of *rca1* from *ca* should be finished before start processing *rca2*, at the same time *rcb1*, *rcd3*, etc, are being processed.

   rca *i* : requests from client a.
5. If processing a request is taking too long, i.e., more than `TIME_OUT`, other requests from the same client can start processing.

Using `dispatch_get_global_queue` and a serial queue`void dispatch_after(
   dispatch_time_t when,
   dispatch_queue_t queue,
   dispatch_block_t block)` for each client would be suboptimal when rca1 processing is finished but `when` has not arrived yet.

Having a serial queue per customer wouldn't satisfy 5.

---

**I'm aware that [GCD is based on a different paradigm](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1) but is there any equivalent of [pthread_mutex_timedlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) or [lockBeforeDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLock/lockBeforeDate%3a) or [Lock.tryLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) in GCD?**

**How to implement the functionality provided by timed locks using GCD?**

[Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the next job block on a dispatch_semaphore with a timeout. You'd need to wait on job submission, though, not just job execution... otherwise GCD will spin up a ton of threads that immediately wait, which is not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, seems like `dispatch_semaphore`s are the way to go.

On this particular case waiting on job execution proved to be better, we don't expect many request from the same client. Waiting on job submission would either increase the complexity or make the submission thread to wait.